# Generate sequence of alphabets in using oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

I have got a task in which I have to generate alphabet sequence on execution of the same oracle query every time.

Example:

- When I execute a query first time, it has to generate A
- When I execute the same query second time, it has to generate B.

So, it should generate A,B,C,D......Z. Once it reaches Z, it has to generate AA,AB,AC.....AZ

How to compose a query?

Comment: . . SQL queries strive to be deterministic.  If you want to change the behavior, you need to parameterize them in some way, or change the underlying data.

Comment: Maybe a sequence and then convert that number into a string like that with modulo?

Comment: Who gave you such a "task"? It makes absolutely no sense. What possible use could you ever make of such an output?

Comment: why does this alphabetic sequence required ??

Comment: @psaraj12 We are using this sequence to append with the numeric values while generating some invoice data and implement this in one of our stored procedures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make sure only this query uses the sequence we can use the below

```
  create table alpha_seq( t number);
  insert into alpha_seq values(0);
```

then use the below function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_alpha_sequence 
    RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
        v_value NUMBER;
        alpha_seq VARCHAR2(4000);
    begin
    update alpha_seq set t=t+1;
    select t into v_value from alpha_seq;
    commit;
    with
     letters
     as
     (select chr( ascii('A')+level-1 ) letter
        from dual
      connect by level <= 26
     ),
     alpha as (select *
      from letters
      union all
     select l1.letter || l2.letter
      from letters l1, letters l2
     union all
      select l1.letter || l2.letter || l3.letter
      from letters l1, letters l2, letters l3)
      select letter into alpha_seq from (select a.*,rownum rw1 from alpha a
      where rownum <=v_value) where rw1=v_value;
      return alpha_seq;
      END;
```

Output:-

```
 select get_alpha_sequence from dual;

 A


 select get_alpha_sequence from dual;

 B
```

Comment: This is working absolutely fine and as per my requirement. Thanks so much .

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your problem

Comment: @psaraj12 It is such a **bad** idea to use a function to do DML transactions and commit. Just imagine how horrible would it be for `read-only` users to use this function just to read the data? If the tablespace is made read-only, you won't be able to use this function at all. **You are just introducing more problems by doing this**. Also, it would be a nightmare to handle such `UDF` during migrations. Should be avoided. Also, an overhead of maintaining another table for sequences is an overkill. If this is used in ETL, it would be simply impossible to maintain. Once again, should be avoided.

Comment: As per OP this sequence is used in generating invoice data and hence there is no question of querying as read-only user this information.

Comment: @psaraj12 Is it possible to achieve the next level of this task as A000 - A999, B000 - B999... Z000 - Z999, AA00 - AA99, AB00 - AB99... ZZ00 - ZZ99? Please let me know if it's possible.

Comment: @NagarajUppar use rpad with sequence to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

Using alphabetical representation for sequence is not a good idea, you should use numerical values. Oracle provides `IDENTITY COLUMN` for this purpose.

If you actually need an alphabet sequence, then you could create a simple `SEQUENCE` and a `FUNCTION` that returns the **alphabet sequence** of your choice. Using [Tom's](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:4136198000346693074) query in the function:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_alpha_seq (seq_val IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    v_val NUMBER;
    alpha_seq VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    v_val := seq_val;
    SELECT case when i3 > 0 then chr(i3+ascii('A')-1) end ||
           case when i2 > 0 then chr(i2+ascii('A')-1) end ||
           chr(i1+ascii('A')-1)
    INTO alpha_seq
      FROM (
    SELECT mod((v_val-1),27) i1,
           mod( trunc((v_val-0.1)/27), 27) i2,
               mod( trunc((v_val-0.1)/27/27), 27 ) i3,
              v_val l
     FROM dual
          )
    WHERE i1 <> 0
      AND NOT( l>= 27*27 and i2 = 0)
      AND NOT( l>= 27*27*27 and i3 = 0);

RETURN alpha_seq;
END;
/
```

Now call this function with the sequence `NEXTVAL` as input:

```
SELECT get_alpha_seq(s.nextval) FROM dual;
```

Demo:

```
SQL> SELECT get_alpha_seq(s.nextval) FROM dual;

GET_ALPHA_SEQ(S.NEXTVAL)
------------------------------
A

SQL> SELECT get_alpha_seq(s.nextval) FROM dual;

GET_ALPHA_SEQ(S.NEXTVAL)
------------------------------
B
```

Similarly, it can return alphabetical sequence like below:

```
A
B
C
...
Z
AA
AB
...
AY
AZ
BA
BB
...
ZZ
AAA
AAB
...
ZZZ
```

Comment: There are probably more issues with this solution than the ones I can see right away. First, you should turn off caching; otherwise you will have gaps if cached sequence values are not used up. This is easy to fix. Harder to fix: How do you make sure that this query and this query only, and noone and nothing else uses value from the sequence. This, aside from the fact that the problem itself is quite meaningless.

Comment: @mathguy In my opinion, sequence should always be pure integer and never a character. To avoid the function, OP can use the same logic instead. However, sequence is required. There are many ways to address the shortcomings. However, I really question the requirement of using alphabetical sequence and not numeric.

Comment: @mathguy Regarding *How do you make sure that this query and this query only, and noone and nothing else uses value from the sequence* Really? So why to have a sequence at all if you cannot guarantee a sequence could be dedicated for a particular process in an application? That much of control is a necessity in any application design. Oracle internally uses lot of sequence objects, so would you ask Oracle *what-if* their developers use same sequence for another feature? In an object oriented programming based application, objects could be easily made sure to be dedicated for particular process

Comment: OK, so how do you, then, ensure that no other query (or INSERT statement, etc.) uses values from the same sequence? Certainly there is nothing in the code you posted that guarantees that. If you do have a proposed solution, rather than generalities, that may help the OP more. (Note that you must do something at the DB level too, no matter what you do in your applications. Otherwise other processes WILL be able to access the sequence.)

Comment: @mathguy `sequence` is an object just like other database objects. Any object that's created in database, is for application purpose. Would you use `SYS` owned objects for regular purpose? Of course not. **How would you restrict someone to not use a table just like sequence?** Once again, OP asked about alphabetical sequence, and I answered that. If I have to post about **nuances** of everything that's involved, then it' not in the scope here. Appreciate your questions, stay safe :-)

Comment: How would I restrict? By not granting them privileges. There is no "privilege" to grant to select from a sequence - especially by the same user (restrict the sequence so it is only used by a specific query, and by nothing else the user does). But I'm wasting my time - I see you are interested in avoiding the question, not addressing it. Be well!

Comment: Alpha vs numeric is not really the issue; even if you wanted a numeric value to be incremented ONLY BY ONE QUERY and by nothing else, you would have exactly the same problem I asked. It's really about using "sequence" for this, no matter how it is then processed.

Comment: @mathguy If you want we could discuss further here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214067/discussion-between-lalit-kumar-b-and-mathguy I am open to  your questions.